# Keyboard short-cut to switch to a specific workspace using Ctrl-[1-8] on numeric keypad

Tags: gnome, compiz, workspaces, shortcut-keys

I have **8 workspaces** in use throughout the day arranged as **2 rows x 4 columns**.

Workspaces are numbered logically from 1-4 for the top row left-right, then 5-8 for the next row.

I would like to be able to switch to a workspace using the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl-num</kbd> where [num] corresponds to number [1-8] on my numeric keypad.

**Gnome/Compiz** already allows me to switch workspaces via <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-up/down/left/right</kbd> or at least that is how I have configured it.

Finding a way to make the mapping and behavior described above however is still confounding me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under `Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts` you can map up to 12 workspaces. You can find needed entries under `Window Management -> Switch to workspace #`.

Comment: So simple, thanks! I was looking in the wrong place i.e. Compiz settings. Thank you.

Comment: You should mark as correct the answer. :)

Comment: When I try this with, say, Ctrl-Alt-Num7, it reports Ctrl-Alt-7 as the hotkey, but instead of taking me to the corresponding workspace, it does something else (eg widens the window with focus). Moreover, hitting Ctrl-Alt-7 does nothing. It works perfectly fine if I set the hotkey as Ctrl-Alt-7 (ie not using the keypad 7 key).

Comment: The problem was that Unity Tweak Tool had Window Snapping turned on. Once I turned it off, the redefinitions for some of the Num keys (Shift-Crtl-Alt-Num? still didn't work) started working.

Comment: Currently I see up to 4 workspaces for which I can assign shortcuts: any idea how to add more? (a lot, I know, but still)

Comment: No surprise, people were talking about it ( https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=826024 ), mentioning a few workarounds, although with a distinctly hackish feel to the proposed solutions.