# How to configure shortcuts for workspaces on MATE 1.6

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz, workspaces, mate, mint

I've successfully configured four workspaces by using the switcher applet, but I can't find where to configure shortcuts (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> to move to the one on the left).

Some resources says it should be under Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts, but I can only find entries for `Sound`, `Desktop` (including lock screen, home folder, search, calc and other apps) and `Custom` ones.

Is something missing in my install? Is it possible to include by hand those shortcuts? Should I just ditch MATE workspaces and use Compiz ones (that do not integrate with the windows applet)?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/9576/keyboard-short-cut-to-switch-to-a-specific-workspace-using-ctrl-1-8-on-numeric?rq=1

Comment: not exactly a duplicate as those options do not appear in my Shortcuts editor

Comment: I have the same problem: I configured my short-cuts in 15.10 and they are retained in 16.04.1, but the **Windows Management** entries are missing from **Keyboard Shortcuts**, although **Help** says they should be there, as does the answer below. I don't know if it's specifically a Mate problem - my 15.10 was Ubuntu Gnome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These settings are normally found in Keyboard Shortcuts:

**System > Preferences > Hardware > Keyboard Shortcuts**

[image: https://roseannastar.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/keyboardshortcuts.png]

Click where it shows the key combo or says 'disabled' and press the key combination you want.

**If you cannot use this feature for some reason or you prefer a CLI method, use Gsettings.**

Here are all the possible keybindings for workspace manipulation and their likely default values:

```
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-left '<Control><Alt>Left'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-11 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-10 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-12 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-prev 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-right '<Control><Alt>Right'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-down '<Control><Alt>Down'
org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings switch-to-workspace-up '<Control><Alt>Up'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-8 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-10 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-12 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-11 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-left '<Control><Shift><Alt>Left'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-down '<Control><Shift><Alt>Down'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-1 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-2 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-3 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-4 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-5 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-6 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-7 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-9 'disabled'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-up '<Control><Shift><Alt>Up'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-right '<Control><Shift><Alt>Right'
org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings toggle-on-all-workspaces 'disabled'
```

To change one use the `gsettings set` command, for example

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-3 '<Mod4>3'
```

This command sets <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> as a shortcut to move the current window to workspace 3.

To remove a keybinding, `set` it to 'disabled'. See `man gsettings` for more detail. You may have to experiment to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: this still doesn't show up in my Ubuntu 16.04 (with backuped homedir from old install). Could this be related to Compiz being used in place of Marco? By running `gsettings get org.mate.Marco.window-keybindings move-to-workspace-3` I did get "disabled", so it's not like the option is gone from my system...

Comment: I remember I posted this question when I had trouble with Compiz and was trying to live without it. Fortunately after a couple of weeks I got that thing sorted out, but it seems those options never showed up in the Keyboard Shortcuts screen.

Comment: Yeah I would guess it was because of using compiz... the schemas will be different presumably. Like in my other comment, try `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i workspace` ... but you fixed it anyway :)

Comment: how can I add a new 'Key'? for example, I want to create a shortcut for 'caja', and when I try something like this: `gsettings set org.mate.Marco.global-keybindings caja '<Control><Alt>e' ` I get this error: `No such key “caja”`

Comment: I solved my problem, enabled a similar menu by installing and launching an app named `gnome-control-center`, when I stumbled upon this question.